# PostgreSQL - SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to SQL.

I guess I've misunderstood the concept of how to use `DISTINCT` keyword.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(e.id), e.text, e.priority, CAST(e.order_number AS integer), s.name AS source, e.modified_time, e.creation_time, (SELECT string_agg(DISTINCT text, '|') FROM definitions WHERE entry_id = d.entry_id) AS definitions 
FROM entries AS e
LEFT JOIN definitions d ON d.entry_id = e.id
INNER JOIN sources s ON e.source_id = s.id
WHERE vocabulary_id = 22
ORDER BY e.order_number
```

The error is as follows:

```
ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 6:  ORDER BY e.order_number
```

Just trying to understand what my `SELECT` statement should look like.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I need to fetch `entries` records and avoid duplicates, Plus I would like to order them by `order_number`.

Comment: To someone who is reading this now, look at the error message, it clearly says something ```isn't present in select query```  list but has been ```trying to use in order by query``` . In this query ```order_number``` doesn't appear in select  but appears in order by which causes the error to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want one row per distinct `e.id`, then you are looking for `distinct on`.  It is very important that the `order by` be consistent with the `distinct on` keys:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (e.id), e.id, e.text, e.priority, CAST(e.order_number AS integer),
       s.name AS source, e.modified_time, e.creation_time,
       (SELECT string_agg(DISTINCT d2.text, '|') FROM definitions d2 WHERE d2.entry_id = d.entry_id) AS definitions 
FROM entries e LEFT JOIN
     definitions d
     ON d.entry_id = e.id INNER JOIN
     sources s
     ON e.source_id = s.id
WHERE vocabulary_id = 22
ORDER BY e.id, e.order_number;
```

Given the subquery, I suspect that there are better ways to write the query.  If that is of interest, ask *another* question, provide sample data, desired results, and a description of the logic.

Comment: thank you! 
`DISTINCT ON (e.id),` - comma is not needed.
also, `ORDER BY e.id, e.order_number;` orders the collection by `id` instead of by `order_number` - swapping them doesn't help for some reason.
I'll keep looking into this.

Comment: Have just resolved it actually:
`SELECT DISTINCT ON (e.order_number) CAST(e.order_number AS integer), e.text, e.priority, e.id, ...`
`... ORDER BY e.order_number, e.id;`

Accepting your answer, great tip, again thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me that you are trying to distinct on a single column and not on others - which is bound to fail.

For example, `select distinct a,b,c from x` returns the unique combinations of a,b and c, not unique a but normal b and c